# i am not able to create dynamic select in spring mvc application inside javascripte

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

i am facing problem while creating a form:select in my spring mvc application inside javascript.

function createSubSelect(divName,pathName,defaultValue,defaultLable,items) {

```
var newDiv=document.createElement('div');
var selectHTML = "";
selectHTML="<form:select path=";
selectHTML += "'"+pathName+"'";
selectHTML += "class=";
selectHTML += "'aa'>";
selectHTML += "<form:option value=";
selectHTML += " '"+defaultValue+"' ";
selectHTML += "label=";
selectHTML += "'"+defaultLable+"'";
selectHTML += ">";
selectHTML += "<form:options items=";
selectHTML +=  "'"+items+"'";
selectHTML += "</form:options>";
selectHTML += "</form:select>";
selectHTML += "<form:errors path=";
selectHTML += "'"+pathName+"'";
selectHTML += "/>";
alert(selectHTML);
document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newDiv);
```

}

please help me where i am mistake.

Comment: You're not appending your `selectHTML` anywhere.

Comment: please explain with example.or let me know what change in above code

Comment: You have to `append` your HTML that you're building. Right now you do nothing with `selectHTML`

Comment: i am having my jsp as it is:   <div id="companyNgoTypeDiv"></div>  and in above java script method passing divName as companyNgoTypeDiv.

Comment: can you please let me know how i can use selectHTML after creating it.

Answer (score 0):

First, it appears you are building a JSP string in JavaScript. This won't work because JSP is evaluated on the server, which sends HTML to the browser. JavaScript needs to deal with HTML and the Document Object Model API.

The basic way to do this is:

```
var newDiv=document.createElement('div');
var selectHTML = [
    '<select name="' + pathName + '" class="aa">',
        '<option value="' + defaultValue + '">' + defaultLable + '</option>',
        '<option value="X">Label 1</option>',
        '<option value="Y">Label 2</option>',
    '</select>'
].join("");

// Inject new HTML into new DIV
newDiv.innerHTML = selectHTML;
// Insert new DIV into page
document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newDiv);
```

Now, you've got a JavaScript variable called `items`, and I'm not sure what it contains. I'm assuming it's some sort of Array. You need to create one `<option value="foo">Bar</option>` for each value in the `items` Array that should appear in the dropdown, where `foo` is the value sent back to the server when that option is selected, and `Bar` is the label visible to the user.